# How to NOT detected by Google image search

Tags: image, google-image-search

I know Google Image Search is very powerful by their face recognition algorithm.

**I wonder is there any way to process/change the images which Google cannot search or detect?**

I tried to change the images (of some famous movies like Batman) to black&white, reduce the resolution or "print-screen" each scene from the movies but they didn't work. Google can find out all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that Google will act the same for text and image crawling.
The easiest way should be to define a robots.txt for your site.

This file can look like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /images/
```

By setting this up, google will not index everything in and below `/images`. Besides google every other well-behaving search engine crawler will consider your robots.txt.

See details about this file [here](http://tools.seobook.com/robots-txt/).